# Using forms on multiple tabs to edit a single entity

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jquery-ui-tabs

In my application I have implemented a page where the user can edit its account information.   Since there are a lot of fields I have broken them up into **p:tab** elements inside a **p:tabView**.   Like this:

```
            <p:tabView dynamic="true" rendered="#{account.accessOK}">
                <p:tab title="Basic Information">
                    <h:form id="formBasic">
                        (some fields here)
                        <p:commandButton value="Save"
                                         action="#{account.doSave()}"
                                         update="formBasic msgs"
                                         />
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Address">
                    <h:form id="formAddress">                           
                        (fields related to address here)
                        <p:commandButton value="Save"
                                         action="#{account.doSave()}"
                                         update="formBasic msgs"
                                         />
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="E-Mail & Phone Numbers">
                     (then another form here with more field)
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Password">
                    <h:form id="formPass">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                              (and this form handles the password)
                        <p:commandButton value="Change"
                                         action="#{account.doPassword()}"
                                         update="msgs"
                                         />
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
```

This seems pretty straightforward but there is a problem.  Each tab has its own form so that the fields that gets processed when the user hits the **p:commandButton** are only those in the form.   However the following sequence will probably confuse the user:

1. Change some fields on one tab but do not click the **Save** button.
2. Go to another tab and fill in fields there, then click the **Save** button.  The fields on that form will be processed.
3. Go back to the tab edited in step 1 above and the fields will look like they have been processed, but have not.   It will be a filled out form but no visual way to tell that the fields have not been saved.

Note that I do not want to put all the tabs into one form and execute all the fields on all the tabs at once.  This is because some field changes might have side effects, such as setting the password.  Also you don't want a validation pass to happen on fields that the user isn't changing during this visit.

So is there any method to solve this user interface deficiency?

Comment: I almost always use ajax to send the values to the server and use a generic commandButton (outside the tabs) to just trigger the 'save' action ON the server and not use it to submit TO the server

Comment: @Kukeltje That sounds like it would work.  Do you mean that each field uses a valueChangeListener instead of using the value attribute?

Comment: No, use the value attribute, but just nest a `p:ajax` tag in the input elements